# Automatic consignment tracking using php

Tags: php, tracking

I'm trying to create a PHP Website for e-commerce. I'm sending my goods to the customers using dtdc,bluedart,indiapost and so on. I want to track the consignments through my website like flipkart. How can I submit the tracking code into the specified website( eg: dtdc ) automatically and fetch data to display in my website. Any Idea? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check with each delivery company. They may have an API that allows you to retrieve the status of the package

Comment: But that is the problem with me. I'm new to API programming. I don't know how to create or retrieve API's and contents from API.Can you suggest any simple API creation code & values retrieving using API. It will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.